# Add SWT widget Group when a checkbox is selected

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I have a GUI which has 3 different sections. In one of the section I have 2 checkboxes.
I want to add one more widget  multiple selection List when one of the checkbox is selected.

I added a selectionListener to checkbox and when it is selected I am calling method which creates multiple selection List.

Problem is this list is not getting added in the GUI when checkbox is selected and it is not removed when checkbox is unchecked.

I am not able to find the cause. Can anybody help me?

Below is the code to add the multiple selection list

```
private void createFirstLevelSubFolderGroup() {
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.verticalAlignment = org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.FILL;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    subFolderGroup = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);        
    subFolderGroup.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    subFolderGroup.setLayoutData(gridData);
    subFolderGroup.setText("First Level SubFolder");           
    firstLevelFolderList = new List(subFolderGroup, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);  
    subFolderGroup.setVisible(true);
    //firstLevelFolderList.setVisible(false);

 } 

 //code where the call to add this list is there
 //code adding a checkbox is here  and below am adding a listener to that checkbox
 ArchiveCheckbox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
           if (ArchiveCheckbox.getSelection()) {  
           // here am trying to call the method which adds multiple selection list
           createFirstLevelSubFolderGroup();                                   
          }         
          else {
            // I want to remove that widget
           subFolderGroup.setVisible(false);                    
           firstLevelFolderList.removeAll();                    
         }
      }
    }
```

Basically I am not able to add this dynamically.

A small code snippet which demonstrates my scenario is fine if the code which I provided doesn't have the req info.

![Below is the gui which I am creating. When check box prepare archive for catch is selected I want a multiple selection list should appear just below the checkbox and it should disappear when it is unchecked. Currently when it is checked multiple selection list appearing but it hides the other group Model that contains sources ][1]

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl2ml.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all the controls at the start. Set a `GridData` layout on each control you want to hide and set the `exclude` flag to true and make in control invisible. So something like:

```java
Control control = .. create control ...

GridData data = new GridData(flags);
data.exclude = true;
control.setLayoutData(data);

control.setVisible(false);
```

When you want to make the controls visible set the `exclude` flag to false, make the control visible and call `layout()` on the parent `Composite`.

```java
GridData data = (GridData)control.getLayoutData();
data.exclude = false;

control.setVisible(true);

parentComposite.layout();
```

Comment: I added the code which you told but still am not able to add the widget dynamically :( :(

Comment: You don't add it, you make it visible or invisible. Show your code

Comment: I am able to make it visible and invisible when checkbox is selected. But I am facing new problem now. When checkbox is selected multiple selection list is getting added to gui. But the other component which was there earlier is now not visible. I guess it is because of size. When I uncheck the checkbox my multilpe list goes off and the other widget is visible.

Comment: I am able to get this behavior too now. I just had to call pack() on parent shell after the above statements. Thank you